# Webscraping articles - individual coauthor data

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping articles published in Milbank Quarterly. I'm especially interested in the data about the authors and their institutional affiliation. I've written code using beautifulsoup and pandas libraries so that my output is saved as a csv. The csv contains one row per article. This means that for articles with multiple authors, the "author" column contains all the authors, and the "institution" column contains all the institutions of authors who coauthored the article. Instead, I want to have the output be that the csv has one row per author; in other words, multiple rows per article. This is because I want to eventually count how many times each institution was represented in the journal.

I used the beautifulsoup `.find_all` method to get all my data. Initially, I tried using `.find_all_next` to get authors and institutions, thinking that would accommodate articles with multiple authors, but that just returned nothing for those columns.

What is the best way for me to rewrite this code so that each author gets their own row?

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

articletype=list()
articlelist=list()
titlelist=list()
vollist=list()
issuenumlist=list()
authorlist = list()
instlist = list()
urllist=list()

issueurllist = ['https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/1', 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/2','https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/3','https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/4']

for issue in issueurllist:
    requrl = requests.get(issue)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requrl.text, 'lxml')

    #Open url of each article.

    baseurl = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com'

    for article in issue:
        doi=[a.get('href') for a in soup.find_all('a', title = "Full text")]

    for d in doi:
        doilink = baseurl + d
        opendoi = requests.get(doilink)
        articlesoup=BeautifulSoup(opendoi.text, 'lxml')

    ```Get metadata for each article```
    for tag in articlesoup:
        arttype=articlesoup.find_all("span", {"class":"primary-heading"})
        title=articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_title"})
        vol=articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_volume"})
        issuenum = articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_issue"})
        author = articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_author"})
        institution=articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_author_institution"})
        url=articlesoup.find_all("meta",{"name":"citation_fulltext_html_url"})

    articletype.append(arttype)
    titlelist.append(title)
    vollist.append(vol)
    issuenumlist.append(issuenum)
    authorlist.append(author)
    instlist.append(institution)
    urllist.append(url)

    milbankdict={'article type':articletype, 'title':titlelist, 'vol':vollist, 'issue':issuenumlist,'author':authorlist, 'author institution':instlist, 'url':urllist}
    milbank2018=pd.DataFrame(milbankdict)
    milbank2018.to_csv('milbank2018.csv')
    print("saved")
````

Comment: `find_all()` gives list so you can use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly.

Comment: you can also use `zip()` to works with many lists at the same time - ie. `for name, address in zip(author, url): print(name, address)`

Answer (score 0):

the [find_all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method always return a list, As you see, I am validating  `tag_object is not None`, this is an important test case because some author does not contain meta attribute then return None. Not required multiple lists for each meta attribute, you can manage with the dictionary, here I am formatting `data by author` and related all meta attribute.

[strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) in-built function of Python is used to remove all the leading and trailing spaces from a string.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

issueurllist = ['https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/1',
                'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/2',
                'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/3',
                'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/4'
                ]

base_url = 'https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com'

json_data = []

for issue in issueurllist:
    response1 = requests.get(issue)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response1.text, 'lxml')

    for article in issue:
        doi=[a.get('href') for a in soup1.find_all('a', title = "Full text")]

    for i in doi:
        article_dict = {"article":"NaN","title":"NaN","vol":"NaN","issue":"NaN","author":"NaN","institution":"NaN","url":"NaN"}
        article_url = base_url + i
        response2 = requests.get(article_url)
        soup2=BeautifulSoup(response2.text, 'lxml')

        '''Get metadata for each article'''

        article = soup2.find("span", {"class":"primary-heading"})
        title = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_title"})
        vol = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_volume"})
        issue  = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_issue"})
        author  = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_author"})
        institution = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_author_institution"})
        url = soup2.find("meta",{"name":"citation_fulltext_html_url"})

        if article is not None:
            article_dict['article']= article.text.strip()

        if title is not None:
            article_dict['title']= title['content'].strip()

        if vol is not None:
            article_dict['vol']= vol['content'].strip()

        if issue is not None:
            article_dict['issue']= issue['content'].strip()

        if author is not None:
            article_dict['author']= author['content'].strip()

        if institution is not None:
            article_dict['institution']= institution['content'].strip()

        if url is not None:
            article_dict['url']= url['content'].strip()

        json_data.append(article_dict)

df=pd.DataFrame(json_data)
df.to_csv('milbank2018.csv')
```

Comment: Your code only retrieves the first author. Coauthors don't get their own row. I am trying to make it so that if an article has multiple authors, each author gets their own row in the output. For articles with multiple authors, there are multiple meta tags with attribute "name=citation_author".

Comment: @C.K. Provide an article URL which is containing more than one author.

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14680009/2018/96/1  >> https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1468-0009.12311   Present within inner links then see meta tags.

Comment: @QHarr provided a good example. Please refer to that article.